# Real time plotting the model predictions while training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Im trying to see how my model trains overtime by seeing its predictions over the real y values on a plot that gets updated on each batch, i googled how its done and its very confusing, the closest i got it to working is the code added here :

```
def cb(x, y_true):
    def _(batch, logs):
        s,e=batch*batch_size,(batch+1)*batch_size
        y_pred = model.predict(
            x[s:e],
            batch_size=batch_size
        )
        plt.clf()
        plt.plot(y_true[s:e], label='true')
        plt.plot(y_pred, label='pred')
        plt.legend()
        plt.show()
    return _
cb_plot=keras.callbacks.LambdaCallback(on_batch_end=cb(train_X,train_y))
```

The problem with this is that i need to close the figure manually everytime in order to continue the training because `show` is blocking. i tried using `block=False` and i tried to enable interactive using `ion` but that got me to an empty white non responding figure window. Anyone has an idea what needs to be changed here to make it work?

BTW i didnt see that TensorBoard can show you the predictions the model has done through the training compared with the real y values, is it possible to see that in tensorboard instead of manually implementing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using matplotlib qt backend with:

```
%matplotlib qt
```

or if you are running .py file

```
from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'qt')
```

then create global `axe` object with `ax = plt.axes()`
and finally use it to draw your plot:

```
def plot_stuff():
   ax.clear()
   x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 50)
   ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))
```

And if you want to plot predicted values, you could create some custom metric fucntions which would simply return `y_true`, or `y_pred` values. And use `TensorBoard` callback to plot it.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me :

```
plt.show(block=False)
```

and then

```
def cb(x, y_true):
    def _(batch, logs):
        s,e=batch*batch_size,(batch+1)*batch_size
        y_pred = model.predict(
            x[s:e],
            batch_size=batch_size
        )
        plt.clf()
        plt.plot(y_true[s:e], label='true')
        plt.plot(y_pred, label='pred')
        plt.axis([0, batch_size, -1, 1])
        plt.legend()
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.0001)
    return _
cb_plot=keras.callbacks.LambdaCallback(on_batch_end=cb(train_X,train_y))
```